# PHP update cookies after a PayPal return call

Tags: php, cookies

So the return is working and I can set the database with the new settings the only issue is getting the cookie to reflect the change in the user status when the time frame expires.

```
if ($prem_user == 1) {
    // prem user
    if ($data->prem_exp < time())
    {
        $query = "UPDATE members SET prem_status='0', prem_exp='0' WHERE id='$data->id'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        // re build Cookie for new information
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$data->email' AND password = '$data->password'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(var_dump($conn));

        if ($result->num_rows != 1) {
            // security issue send to index for logic to handle
            header("LOCATION : /index.php");
        }

        $data = json_encode($result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        setcookie('account', $data, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have trouble understanding the issue. Is the problem that your `setcookie` is not setting the cookie?

Comment: Correct there is already a cookie set as $_COOKIE['account'] and i am trying to put new information in to it.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the script execution reaches that line? if you do `var_dump($data);exit;` just after the `setcookie`, does the data show up on screen?

Comment: yeah i have double checked it dose, thats why it made me come here i just cant for the life of me work it out i will add the whole script as it stands in a sec

Comment: what shows up if you do `var_dump(headers_sent());` immediately *before* the cookie line. What do you see if you dump the result of your setcookie call: `var_dump(setcookie(...));`

Comment: the first output is bool(true) 2nd is bool(false) 

so it is not writing the cookie how would i found out why??

Comment: I've written an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some background:**

An HTTP response (from your server to the browser) includes headers that tell the browser about the content, and the content itself. Headers must be sent before content. Cookies are set within headers.

**The problem**

Your `setcookie` doesn't work because it occurs after some content has been sent to the browser (we know this because `headers_sent()` is `true`. Content includes anything outside of the PHP tags `<?php` `?>` including any HTML and any blank space before the opening tag.

**Solution 1**

An alternative fix is to use output buffering. This means that when you send content to the browser, PHP will hold it in the buffer until the buffer is full or the script ends. If you later send some headers (eg: with `setcookie`), you will have no problem since nothing has actually been sent to the browser.

To use this solution, start the output buffer before any content is sent:

```
<?php
ob_start();
```

Then at the end of your script, flush the buffer. This sends everything in the buffer to the browser

```
ob_end_flush();
```

[See the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Note: you can set PHP to automatically, always use output buffering by setting the buffer size (how much it can hold before it is forcibly sent to the browser) in **php.ini**

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

**Solution 2**

The solution is to set the cookie before any content is sent. If you're not sure where you're sending content, execute the code below instead of your `setcookie`:

```
$file=null;
$line=null;
if(headers_sent($file,$line)){
    //headers have been sent. too late to set a cookie
    die("Can't set cookie: Content sent in $file on line $line");
}else{
    setcookie(...); // cookie header can still be set.
}
```

The message will give you the filename and line number where you first sent content to the browser.

[See the docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php)

Comment: i found this answer about 30 mins ago through some exploring - you are right in my Bootstrap i had a header been send for debug reasons.